# Disable vertical scrolling in UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableViewCell`.  The height of the table view cell is set to the height of the collection view so the collection view only scrolls horizontally.

Sometimes when scrolling in the table view the collection view will capture the vertical scrolls and bounce scroll vertically.  I've set the `height` to `0` in `-collectionViewContentSize` in my custom layout.

How do I completely disable vertical scrolling in a collection view?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your storyboard - click your `UICollectionView` and open Utilities. Under the Attributes Inspector, center button, look to 'Bounces'. Uncheck "Bounces Vertically".

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm doing this programmatically.

Comment: collectionView.alwaysBounceVetical = NO;

Comment: `collectionView..alwaysBounceVertical = false`

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable vertical scrolling in a UICollectionView **programatically**, add the following to your viewDidLoad() method

```
self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Example:

```
class YourCollectionView: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    // Then your methods for creating cells and layout, etc
}
```